# Why did the WAU try to 'repair' Johan Ross?

Tags: soma

I have been going through the great story of SOMA. But I can't understand **why the WAU tried to revive Johan Ross after he was found brain dead in the Climber ?**

I am convinced that the WAU actually tried to kill Johan Ross out of the impulse of  self preservation.  But if that is the case then why did the WAU want to revive Johan, once he was placed under observation in Omicron ?

This makes no sense to me.

Comment: My assumption was that the WAU revived him as a puppet like all the others, but this guy somehow kept his sanity (only theories about how) and began to hide from the WAU with the intent to destroy it.

Comment: @GnomeSlice The WAU was pretty intelligent. What makes Ross so special that the WAU would revive him knowing that Ross like other may have wanted to destroy the WAU.

Comment: Well the WAU was able to control most (all?) of the other puppets it reanimated.  Perhaps Ross was just a fluke?  There are some theories about how he kept his mind on reddit and such places

Comment: @GnomeSlice Umm, reddit ???